# Assign counter to object property javascript C#

Tags: javascript, c#

What I am trying is to dynamically append elements with three different functions with ajax.

Every function is called on click. What I can`t manage is to print the elements in the order they were appended.

My C# objects have property Number, which is supposed to help me keep the order but I seem to have trouble assigning a counter in a function to a property of a C# object, it always shows 0.

Here is some of my code:
declaring the variable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/112h8.png)

I want every time when an html element is created, this variable to be incremented, I do this like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwLlN.png)
The thing is, that I want to keep the value of that counter for each object after that, so I can store it in a property. Not working, but this is how I do it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA7xO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHmm2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Fhl.png)

Comment: Hi! Can you show us your code here. Perhaps you only need transform your counter in a session variable or static variable.

Comment: @janmbaco I apologize for the ugly update, I don`t yet have permissions to do many things, so I work with what I have haha. I am trying to implement a survey form which I render dynamically. The thing is, that I need to render the wuestions in the same order they were created. I have three functions for every type of question I have and I need a global variable to keep track on the order of the items

Answer (score 0):

Use `var globalCounter = 0`, It must work well

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
 var text = ++globalCounter;
  $("#idText").text(text);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p id="idText">0</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>

<script>
  var globalCounter = 0;

</script>
```

Use `var globalCounter` instead of let.

Comment: I tried it and it works! Thank, the thing now is that I am not able to save the current state of this counter to the property of the object I have. I do this: let numberOfQuestionMCQ = document.getElementById("globalCounter").value; and after that assign it to the property I have like this   let MultipleChouceQuestionViewModel = {}  MultipleChouceQuestionViewModel.QuestionNumber = numberOfQuestionMCQ;

                    MCQlist.push(MultipleChouceQuestionViewModel); AGAIN - SORRY FOR THE UGLY PASTING..still learning..

Comment: You don't set nothing in the element by id 'globalCounter'. You have the value in the variable globalCounte, I dont know, the elemet 'globalCounter' for wath you need

Comment: You said that I dont need to save that data to the property or you dont do it in the example you gave me? I need that information for the time I want to use it again. What happens when I save this object with all its properties to the database and want to retreive it again? I don`t hold the number of that question anywhere. So there is no way to again list the items of the collection in the order I need them to be.